# HAR file to Open API convertor

Tags: typescript, openapi, openapi-generator

Disclaimer, I'm about a day into TypeScript right now. I've finally got everything set up in VS Code. I've imported the `har-to-openapi` tool. But I'm puzzled by the documentation. Under "Usage" we find:

```
import { generateSpec } from "har-to-openapi";
const openapi = await generateSpec(har);
const { spec, yamlSpec } = openapi;
// spec = { ... } openapi spec schema document
// yamlSpec = string, "info: ..."
```

But I don't see anywhere in the [docs](https://github.com/jonluca/har-to-openapi) how I would pass in the HAR file I have. Is it assumed that if I'm at this level I should know what I'm doing?

I have a hunch that I need to somehow pass the file so when I run this it will output what I need (in the current directory). Anybody use this before or are you able to provide some assistance?

Thanks.

I've read through the MDN docs, TypeScript Docs/tutorials, VS Code docs, and some of the JavaScript docs on MDN. An actual example would be helpful for me to understand the workflow.

Comment: It looks like you need to pass the HAR in `generateSpec(har)`. Have a look at the [project's tests](https://github.com/jonluca/har-to-openapi/blob/main/test/parameter.test.ts#L12) for examples of how to read & pass the HAR files.

Comment: @Helen, that is helpful. I wouldn't have known to look there. This gives me some more to go on. I was able to do another day of research and realized I needed to clone the entire repository (for everything to work). Thank you for the tip!